# Puppet: substitute parameter in fact name

Tags: puppet

Here is custom fact:

```
require 'etc'

Etc.passwd do |user|
    Facter.add("homedir_#{user.name}".intern) do
        setcode { user.dir }
    end
end
```

It determine users home dir locations.

Here is defined type:

```
define ssh_keys::key ($user) {

    $home = $::homedir_#{user}

    if $home != undef {

    file { "$home/.ssh/":
        ensure => directory,
    }

    file { "$home/.ssh/authorized_keys":
        ensure => file,
        source => "puppet:///modules/ssh_keys/$user",
        }
    }

}
```

It does not work with `$::homedir_#{user}`, but works with exactly defined fact: `$::homedir_root`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
$mule = "ipaddress_${name}"
$donkey = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar(mule) %>")
```